# Олимпиадная задачка проходит не все тесты C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада, шахматы

**Задача**

Шахматная доска - игровое поле, часть инвентаря для игры в шахматы. Существует классический вариант шахматной доски, предназначенный для игры в традиционные шахматы, а также множество вариантов, предназначенных для игры во многочисленные варианты шахмат. В нашей задаче нужно составить доску для особого варианта игры. Эта доска будет составлена из кубиков белого и черного цвета и иметь специальный размер N на M клеток. В наличии есть A кубиков черного цвета и B кубиков белого цвета. Можно ли составить из них нужную доску, если первая клетка нижней строки всегда должна быть черной?

**Формат входных данных**

В первой строке дано два натуральных числа N и M (1 ≤ N, M ≤ 1000). Во второй строке даны два натуральных числа A и B (1 ≤ A, B ≤ 1000000) - количество кубиков черного и белого цвета
соответственно.

**Формат результата**

Выведите слово YES, если можно составить доску N на M, иначе выведите слово NO.

**Примеры**

**Входные данные**

*5 5*

*13 12*

**Результат работы**

*YES*

Ниже мой код, который проходит не все тесты, что не так с моим кодом? Помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, m, a, b;
    cin >> n >> m >> a >> b;
    if (n != m) {
        cout << "NO";
    }
    else if ((n*m >= a + b) && (a >= b)) {
        cout << "YES";
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO";
    }
}
```

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, логику условий в ифе

Comment: Первый иф, если у нас поле не равное кол-во клеток на равное кол-во клеток.

Comment: А разве условие оговаривает, что доска квадратная?

Comment: нет, ладно, это лишние строчки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, этого будет достаточно:

```
if ((a >= n*m-n*m/2)&&(b >= n*m/2))
```

Почему так? - если хотя бы одно измерение доски чётное, то количество чёрных и белых клеток одинаково, иначе чёрных на единицу больше, что и учитывается при целочисленном делении.

Answer (score 1):

Доска же может быть не квадратной, N*M == A + B всегда должно быть равно
Далее по замощению если хотя бы M или N четное то A должно быть равно B

0 =
= 0

0 = 0
= 0 =

0 = 0
= 0 =
0 = 0
= 0 =

Могу это описать как, что доску можно разделить на пары клеток где в каждой паре белая и черная клетка.

Если N и M нечетные тогда у нас начинается чередование по рядам где в одной ряду больше на одну белую а в другом на одну черную, но так как начальный ряд по заданию начинается с черной -> все ряды между собой компенсируются кроме одного где будет на одну черную больше (A == B + 1)

= 0 = 2ч 1б 3 ряд
0 = 0 1ч 2б 2 ряд
= 0 = 2ч 1б 1 ряд

Все ряды кроме 1 будут иметь себе пару которая уравняет количество белых и черных, любая большая размерность сводится к этой или даже к более простой:

= 1ч 0б 1 ряд

Путем удаление пар